# Does destroying the spam account actually protects us?

Tags: discussion

Today I deleted I don't know how many accounts, but noticed that there was one that kept appearing with the same IP. In all cases I did a clean and brutal destroy of the account (Bloody mess actually, account parts everywhere). But then I thought, if there is a way to protect the site (Ban the account/IP) when destroying it so it does not appear for a long time.

There are days that there is 0% spam. Others is like we are in war with other stack exchange sites. So for this cases, how can we deal with spam related incidents in a way that the IP can not be used for several days (Instead of getting used 30 seconds later with another account and with another spam).

Answer (score 10):

Well, I don't think it really protects us, but it does seem to stop some spammers for a while. One thing I would suggest is *not* to send them a message, as it just makes them think we are fooled by them.

Answer (score 10):

You can directly ask the SE team for a URL blacklist or an IP ban if you notice a particular pattern in the spam. Just ping someone from the comm team in the Teacher's Lounge if you get a lot of similar spam.

IP bans are of questionable use and can easily cause too much collateral damage, so they are only used carefully.

Answer (score -1):

If those spammers uses modem with dynamic IP, banning IP can be not useful enough, since *their IP changes as time their reconnects*.

Comment: You missed the part about a URL blacklist in Mad Scientist's post.